# paste a vector to a filtered data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with the following code line:

```
BusinessAZ[(BusinessAZ['county']=='Na') | (BusinessAZ['county']=='error code')].loc[:,'county'] = counties
```

What I trying to do is to replace the existing values in the column 'county' in the filtered data frame 'BusinessAZ' with the values contains in the vector 'counties'.

The vector and the filtered data frame BusinessAZ have the same length.

Here there is an illustrative example:

'BusinessAZ' data frame
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UauHd.png)

'counties' vector

['copin', 'copin', 'copin']

I want to replace the values 'Na' and 'error' in the filtered data frame with the values of the vector 'counties'

```
C:\Users\Juan Carlos\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1745: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  isetter(ilocs[0], value)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlsLD.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Kinds regards

Juan C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For debugging help, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including sample input and expected/desired output.  It is not clear what you mean by "pasting each of the vector 'counties' to a new row called 'county' in the data frame 'BusinessAZ'."  Are you trying to create new rows or replace values in existing rows? Why do you call 'county' row?  You are treating it as column label in your code. And is the `counties` vector the same length as the number of rows returned by your filter?

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67461187/edit) the question and add an example and clarifying details.

Comment: Replace `BusinessAZ[(BusinessAZ['county']=='Na') | (BusinessAZ['county']=='error code')].loc[:,'county'] = counties` with `BusinessAZ.loc[(BusinessAZ['county']=='Na') | (BusinessAZ['county']=='error code'), 'county'] = counties`